# How to find the distance between the first and last 1 in an 8-bit binary number

Tags: algorithm, assembly, binary

I need to write an assembly program which gives me the widest of 32 8-bit numbers from memory. I'm given an array of memory space, with each address corresponding to one 8-bit word. I need to move each number into a register, and then find the width. In this case, the width means the distance between the first and last 1.

ex:

> 00000000 = 0
>
> 00010000 = 1
>
> 00101000 = 3
>
> 10000001 = 8

For this program, I have to create my own instruction set. Each instruction is 8-bits long, so I cannot have overly long branches either.

My main problem is figuring out how to calculate the "width". Once I have an idea of how to do that, I should be able to figure out how to use 8-bit instructions to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, but if you need to create your own instruction set, just create calculate-width instruction.

Answer (score 3):

In x86 (386+) assembly there are `bsf` (bit scan forward) and `bsr` (bit scan reverse). With `bsf` you get the index of the least significant bit set to 1, and with `bsr` the index of the most significant bit set to 1. The difference of these plus 1 is the required distance or width in bits. I believe that equivalents of these instructions can be implemented in your own processor too.

Comment: this might be exactly what I was looking for! Not sure if I am allowed to implement a bsf/bsr though. Technically it doesn't say I can't, but the class is loosely based on the MIPS architecture and I can't find an equivalent instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its possible on your processor but on x86 i would rotate until first carry is set (carry is set to 1 if you last rotated out 1) and store the number of rotations, then do the same except you do it to opposite side and then it should be (8 - sum of those two margins).

Comment: Well, for this assignment, I'm basically creating my own processor, so anything is possible! I never thought of adding a carry bit. Thank you!

Comment: I dont think that would be very effective since the table would take 256 bytes, if I understand your idea properly...

Comment: A look up table would be the logical choice, given modern memory space and what not, but I think for this assignment, it would be too large to implement. What with only 8-bits per instruction.